# Adding a special column to an existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a column containing three values to an existing data frame in a loop, each time appending to an existing row:

existing data frame is MktData with many rows like this:

```
    BidPrice AskPrice  Last Volume
XLU    39.14    39.15 39.15   9242
```

and the new column consists of three values like this called weights `100, 200, 300`

so the final data frame should be

```
    BidPrice AskPrice  Last Volume      weights
XLU    39.14    39.15 39.15   9242 100,200,300
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `paste`.

```
df$weights<-paste0(c(100,200,300),collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
df$weights <- list(c(100,200,300))
#     BidPrice AskPrice  Last Volume       weights
# XLU    39.14    39.15 39.15   9242 100, 200, 300
```

But be aware that the `weights` column is a `list`.

Comment: thank you, both examples work!